# How to check if GitHub PR has been approved by a codeowner?

Tags: github, github-api

I'm building a service which scans for open pull requests with a specified tag, and merges them automatically if they have been reviewed appropriately.

In some cases, PR's will include changes to files owned by a team in the CODEOWNERS file. To my knowledge, GitHub API has no support for Code Owners.

Is this true? Is there any way to verify whether a PR has been reviewed by a Code Owner? I cannot find any discerning info in the API responses which identify whether or not a review is by a Code Owner or just another user.

Thanks!

Comment: did you ever figure out a solution to this?

Comment: @Sam unfortunately I did not. I had to write the functionality myself.

Answer (score 0):

Github provides an API for pending reviews, without differentiating whether that reviewer is a `CODEOWNER` or not.
From what I understand, this service needs to check whether there are pending reviews on the PR, so in this case it doesn't matter if its a codeowner or not, because your call to [github API reviews](https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/reviews/#list-reviews-on-a-pull-request) will return that there are indeed pending reviews.

Another tool you can use is [codeowners-api](https://www.npmjs.com/package/codeowners-api) which can help you understand map whether the reviewers on a PR are indeed `CODEOWNERS`

*Disclaimer - I wrote the library*